# Connecting a BlinkM to a PICAXE

Tags: picaxe, blinkm

Has anyone been able to get a [PICAXE](http://www.picaxe.com/) working with the [BlinkM](http://thingm.com/products/blinkm)? What is the I2C speed?

Answer (score 4):

Do you mean standard i2c speeds or something specific to picaxes or blinkM?

"The standard clock (SCL) speed for I2C up to 100KHz. Philips do define faster speeds: Fast mode, which is up to 400KHz and High Speed mode which is up to 3.4MHz."

quoted from http://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/using_the_i2c_bus.htm

EDIT: Found this: http://getsatisfaction.com/thingm/topics/picaxe_communication which should give you at least something to test your setup with.

Answer (score 2):

This was useful:

http://getsatisfaction.com/thingm/topics/picaxe_communication