# How do I transition from using the Arduino IDE to plain avrdude/make?

Tags: arduino, software, atmega, programmer

> Part three of a three part series on transitioning from Arduino to a plain AVR microcontroller and minimum supporting components ([part one](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67112/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-application-from-something-prototyped-with-arduino9), [part two](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/67080/how-should-one-switch-from-using-an-arduino-as-a-programmer-to-an-external-progrr))

I already know how to use [an Arduino as a programmer for an ATmega](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/109/6), and I know how to use [an external programmer for the ATmega/Arduino using the Arduino IDE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/207/6).

What do I need to know to start programming an ATmega<sup>1</sup> with the command line tools? A brief overview of the different language features and steps to make/upload would be nice.

<sup>1. ATmega328, or a smaller/cheaper AVR microcontroller, even an ATTiny if possible, which will still run the applicaton: See [this post](http://hlt.media.mit.edu/?p=1695) for some details on shrinkifying to an ATTiny.</sup>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The tool I would use in this case is [Cduino](http://brittonkerin.com/cduino/home_page.html). Cduino is a tool designed to give **greater control** over the actions of the ATmega and doesn't require a bootloader.

> The cduino project tries to make it simpler to migrate from the arduino to simpler hardware setups, in particular those that lack a USB serial interface and bootloader. This may be interesting to users for whom cost definitely is a factor.

You will need a USB programming cable, and a Duemilanove or an Uno as it uses the Mega328p chip. Of course, Uno's and Duemilanove's seem to be the most common, so this *shouldn't* be an issue. You will also want an ISP (examples given in the first part of the question) for in-system programming (i.e. to avoid the bootloader).

> It's a lots like the excellent arduino project and uses the same open hardware, but avoids the new wiring language, the C++ intermediate layer, and the Java-based IDE.

Cduino itself is a command line tool which allows you to write directly to the Arduino. You will need a few packages installed, including `make`, `avrdude` and `screen`. To make it run without the bootloader, connect the Arduino as I explained in the previous question, and in the `generic.mk` file change `UPLOAD_METHOD` from `arduino_bl` to `AVRISPmkII`.

Uploading the file itself is a simple command line sequence:

```
make -R -C <program_name> writeflash
```

Then, to communicate with the board serially, use:

```
make -R -C term_io writeflash 
make -R -C term_io run_screen
```

There is a series of 'lessons' to write code for Cduino [here](http://brittonkerin.com/cduino/lessons.html). It is basically C, but with a few library functions specific to the ATMega328p chip - note that it is **C, NOT C++**.